# Referencing an object property that has dashes in the name

Tags: php, syntax, properties, simplexml

I have an xml document with tags that have two dashes in them, like so: `<item--1>`. I'm using SimpleXML to parse this document, so it gives me object properties with the name of the tag. This apparently is a problem, I guess because dashes are invalid characters for variable and property names.

```
<?php

$xml = "<data><fruits><item>apple</item><item--1>bananna</item--1></fruits></data>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach( $xml->children() as $child ) {
  var_dump($child->item);
#  var_dump($child->item--1);
}
```

When you run this, you get

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
}
```

But if you uncomment the last line, the xml element with two dashes, you get an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in test.php on line 17
```

I tried using curly braces:

```
var_dump($child->{item--1});
```

But that only gave me this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DEC
```

which is the decrement operator, or `--`.

How can I reference the properties on this object?

Comment: What does `var_dump($child)` yield?

Comment: `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {
  ["item"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["item--1"]=>
  string(7) "bananna"
}
` which, while it doesn't break, doesn't really allow me to access data. They're not array elements that I can reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach with the curly braces wasn't too wrong, but you need a string between the braces:

```
var_dump($child->{'item--1'});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual's page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php#106500) on `SimpleXMLElement` object:

> Warning to anyone trying to parse XML with a key name that includes a hyphen ie.)

```
<subscribe>
  <callback-url>example url</callback-url>
</subscribe>
```

> In order to access the callback-url you will need to do something like the following:

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($input);
  $callback = $xml->{"callback-url"};
?>
```

> If you attempt to do it without the curly braces and quotes you will find out that you are returned a 0 instead of what you want.